# Material-UI nested radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm trying to do nested radiobuttons with material-ui and redux-form, but i've come a bit short on how to accomplish this.

What i'm trying to accomplish:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmCX7.gif
(Have more form options appear when a radiobutton is selected.)

My current code without nesting:

```js
const renderRadioGroup = ({ input, ...rest }) => (
  <RadioButtonGroup
    {...input}
    {...rest}
    valueSelected={input.value}
    onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(value)}
  />
);
```

Used somewhere like this:

```js
<Field name="sex" component={renderRadioGroup}>
      <RadioButton value="male" label="male" />
      <RadioButton value="female" label="female" />
</Field>
```

What i've tried:

```js
<Field name="sex" component={renderRadioGroup}>
      <RadioButton value="male" label="male" />
      <div /*logic to only render this div when "male" is selected*/>
            <Field name="foo" component={renderRadioGroup}>
                  <RadioButton value="bar" label="bar" />
                  <RadioButton value="qux" label="qux" />
            </Field>
      </div>
      <RadioButton value="female" label="female" />
</Field>
```

But that doesn't work. As it gives me the following error:
**Invariant Violation

input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.**